# Comma separated strings on a @HeaderParam with JAX-RS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I've annotated this method as follow:

```
@PUT
@Path("/categorize")
public abstract Response categorize(
    @HeaderParam(value = "resourceIds") List<String> resourceIds,
    List<MetaInfoValueDTO> metainfos);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to receive a `List<String>`. My client sends this strings using a comma separated format: "s1, s2, s3". The problem is JAX-RS deserialize this received string in one element: so `resourceIds` is a `List<String>` with one element.

Can I modify this behavior?
Note: I'm using a generic Java EE libraries in order to build my JAX-RS application: `providedCompile 'org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-7.0:1.0.3.Final'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884930/jax-rs-headerparam-with-list-populated-with-only-one-comma-separated-element